# Erro em programa de média em C, na exibição de resultado

Tags: c#, c, c++

Sou iniciante em programação em C, e na faculdade tivemos que desenvolver um programa para fazer a média de 4 notas, e depois de digitadas, fazer a exibição, o programa funciona sem erro de sintaxe, mas há alguma coisa de errada no resultado final, que exibe o resultado de média, para mim, qualquer valor que eu coloque ele retorna o resultado como 0. Alguém pode me dizer onde está o erro? O programa é esse:

```
int main()
{
    float media,nota1,nota2,nota3,nota4;
    printf("\nEntre com as 4 notas: \n");
        scanf("%f" ,&nota1);
        scanf("%f" ,&nota2);
        scanf("%f" ,&nota3);
        scanf("%f" ,&nota4);
    media=(nota1+nota2+nota3+nota4)/4;
    printf("\nA media e': %f", &media);
}
```

Comment: Aqui: `printf("\nA media e': %f", &media);` não tem este `&` antes de media. Use: `printf("\nA media e': %f", media);`. Note que é na função scanf é que devemos fornecer o endereço da variável.

Comment: Agora que você mostrou que eu lembrei mesmo que não pode ter o `&` no printf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O programa corrigido é esse:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    float media,nota1,nota2,nota3,nota4;
    printf("\nEntre com as 4 notas: \n");
        scanf("%f", &nota1);
        scanf("%f", &nota2);
        scanf("%f", &nota3);
        scanf("%f", &nota4);
    media=(nota1+nota2+nota3+nota4)/4;
    printf("\nA media e': %f", media);
}
```